# Windows Forms `ControlCollection` implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, reinventing-the-wheel, thread-safety

I've implemented my own version of the `Control.ControlCollection` class in `System.Windows.Forms` and obviously I want it reviewed.

I've tried to make it thread-safe all around, but I'm sure I missed something.

My main concern is obviously the thread-safety of it, but I also would like any other comments as well.

The GitHub version as of this code is at: [Control.ControlCollection](https://github.com/EBrown8534/Framework/blob/de9d7449bd4223cbdfd93f70a75c029fc1208a22/Evbpc.Framework.Windows/Forms/Control.ControlCollection.cs).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Evbpc.Framework.Windows.Forms
{
    public abstract partial class Control : Component, IComponent, IDisposable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a collection of <see cref="Control"/> objects.
        /// Is not actually inherited from ArrangedElementCollection. ArrangedElementCollection was removed from this implementation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection(v=vs.110).aspx
        /// </remarks>
        [ListBindable(false)]
        public class ControlCollection : IEnumerable, ICloneable, IList, ICollection
        {
            private object _syncRoot = new object();
            private object _internalSyncRoot = new object();

            private List<Control> _controls;
            private Control _owner;

            #region Constructors
            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Control.ControlCollection"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="owner">A <see cref="Control"/> representing the control that owns the control collection.</param>
            public ControlCollection(Control owner)
            {
                _owner = owner;
                _controls = new List<Control>();
            }
            #endregion

            #region Properties
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets the number of elements in the collection.
            /// </summary>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.layout.arrangedelementcollection.count(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public virtual int Count
            {
                get
                {
                    lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                    {
                        return _controls.Count;
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets a value indicating whether the collection is read-only.
            /// </summary>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.layout.arrangedelementcollection.isreadonly(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public virtual bool IsReadOnly => false;

            /// <summary>
            /// Indicates the <see cref="Control"/> at the specified indexed location in the collection.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="index">The index of the control to retrieve from the control collection.</param>
            /// <returns>The <see cref="Control"/> located at the specified index location within the control collection.</returns>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/333f9hk4(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public virtual Control this[int index]
            {
                get
                {
                    lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                    {
                        return _controls[index];
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Indicates a <see cref="Control"/> with the specified key in the collection.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="key">The name of the control to retrieve from the control collection.</param>
            /// <returns>The <see cref="Control"/> with the specified key within the <see cref="Control.ControlCollection"/>.</returns>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1865435(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public virtual Control this[string key]
            {
                get
                {
                    lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                    {
                        foreach (Control c in _controls)
                        {
                            if (c.Name == key)
                            {
                                return c;
                            }
                        }

                        throw new KeyNotFoundException();
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets the control that owns this <see cref="ControlCollection"/>.
            /// </summary>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.owner(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public Control Owner => _owner;
            #endregion

            #region Methods
            /// <summary>
            /// Adds the specified control to the control collection.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="value">The <see cref="Control"/> to add to the control collection.</param>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public virtual void Add(Control value)
            {
                lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                {
                    InternalAdd(value);
                }
            }

            private void InternalAdd(Control value)
            {
                if (_owner == value)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"The control {nameof(value)} cannot be the same as the {nameof(Owner)}.");
                }

                value.TabIndex = _controls.Count;
                _controls.Add(value);
                value.Parent = _owner;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Adds an array of control objects to the collection.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="controls">An array of <see cref="Control"/> objects to add to the collection.</param>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.addrange(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public virtual void AddRange(Control[] controls)
            {
                foreach (Control control in controls)
                {
                    Add(control);
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Removes all controls from the collection.
            /// </summary>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public virtual void Clear()
            {
                lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                {
                    _controls.Clear();
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Determines whether the specified control is a member of the collection.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="control">The <see cref="Control"/> to locate in the collection.</param>
            /// <returns>true if the <see cref="Control"/> is a member of the collection; otherwise, false.</returns>
            public bool Contains(Control control)
            {
                lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                {
                    return _controls.Contains(control);
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Determines whether the <see cref="Control.ControlCollection"/> contains an item with the specified key.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="key">The key to locate in the <see cref="Control.ControlCollection"/>.</param>
            /// <returns>true if the <see cref="Control.ControlCollection"/> contains an item with the specified key; otherwise, false.</returns>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.containskey(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public virtual bool ContainsKey(string key)
            {
                lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                {
                    foreach (Control c in _controls)
                    {
                        if (c.Name == key)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Copies the entire contents of this collection to a compatible one-dimensional <see cref="Array"/>, starting at the specified index of the target array.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="array">The one-dimensional <see cref="Array"/> that is the destination of the elements copied from the current collection. The array must have zero-based indexing.</param>
            /// <param name="index">The zero-based index in array at which copying begins.</param>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.layout.arrangedelementcollection.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Searches for controls by their <see cref="Name"/> property and builds an array of all the controls that match.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="key">The key to locate in the <see cref="Control.ControlCollection"/>.</param>
            /// <param name="searchAllChildren">true to search all child controls; otherwise, false.</param>
            /// <returns>An array of type <see cref="Control"/> containing the matching controls.</returns>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public Control[] Find(string key, bool searchAllChildren)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Retrieves the index of the specified child control within the control collection.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="child">The <see cref="Control"/> to search for in the control collection.</param>
            /// <returns>A zero-based index value that represents the location of the specified child control within the control collection.</returns>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fz293fh(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public int GetChildIndex(Control child)
            {
                lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                {
                    if (_controls.Contains(child))
                    {
                        return _controls.IndexOf(child);
                    }

                    throw new KeyNotFoundException();
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Retrieves the index of the specified child control within the control collection, and optionally raises an exception if the specified control is not within the control collection.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="child">The <see cref="Control"/> to search for in the control collection.</param>
            /// <param name="throwException">true to throw an exception if the <see cref="Control"/> specified in the child parameter is not a control in the <see cref="Control.ControlCollection"/>; otherwise, false.</param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta8fcz9s(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public virtual int GetChildIndex(Control child, bool throwException)
            {
                lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                {
                    if (_controls.Contains(child))
                    {
                        return _controls.IndexOf(child);
                    }

                    if (throwException)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException();
                    }

                    return -1;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Retrieves a reference to an enumerator object that is used to iterate over a <see cref="Control.ControlCollection"/>.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>An <see cref="IEnumerator"/>.</returns>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158431(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public virtual IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => _controls.GetEnumerator();

            /// <summary>
            /// Retrieves the index of the specified control in the control collection.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="control">The <see cref="Control"/> to locate in the collection.</param>
            /// <returns>A zero-based index value that represents the position of the specified <see cref="Control"/> in the <see cref="Control.ControlCollection"/>.</returns>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public int IndexOf(Control control)
            {
                lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                {
                    return _controls.IndexOf(control);
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Retrieves the index of the specified control in the control collection.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="key">The <see cref="Control"/> to locate in the collection.</param>
            /// <returns>A zero-based index value that represents the position of the specified <see cref="Control"/> in the <see cref="Control.ControlCollection"/>.</returns>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public virtual int IndexOfKey(string key)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Removes the specified control from the control collection.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="value">The <see cref="Control"/> to remove from the <see cref="Control.ControlCollection"/>.</param>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.remove(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public virtual void Remove(Control value)
            {
                lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                {
                    _controls.Remove(value);
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Removes a control from the control collection at the specified indexed location.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="index">The index value of the <see cref="Control"/> to remove.</param>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public void RemoveAt(int index)
            {
                lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                {
                    _controls.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Removes the child control with the specified key.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="key">The name of the child control to remove.</param>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.removebykey(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public virtual void RemoveByKey(string key)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Sets the index of the specified child control in the collection to the specified index value.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="child">The child <see cref="Control"/> to search for.</param>
            /// <param name="newIndex">The new index value of the control.</param>
            /// <remarks>
            /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </remarks>
            public virtual void SetChildIndex(Control child, int newIndex)
            {
                lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                {
                    if (_controls.Contains(child))
                    {
                        if (newIndex >= Count)
                        {
                            _controls.Remove(child);
                            _controls.Add(child);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _controls.Remove(child);
                            _controls.Insert(newIndex, child);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException();
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Explicit Interface Implementations
            object ICloneable.Clone()
            {
                lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                {
                    ControlCollection clone = new ControlCollection(_owner);
                    clone._controls = _controls;
                    return clone;
                }
            }

            bool ICollection.IsSynchronized { get { return true; } }
            object ICollection.SyncRoot { get { return _syncRoot; } }

            int IList.Add(object control)
            {
                var controlControl = control as Control;

                if (controlControl != null)
                {
                    lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                    {
                        InternalAdd(controlControl);

                        return _controls.Count;
                    }
                }

                return -1;
            }

            void IList.Clear()
            {
                Clear();
            }

            bool IList.Contains(object value)
            {
                var valueControl = value as Control;

                if (valueControl != null)
                {
                    return Contains(valueControl);
                }

                return false;
            }

            int IList.IndexOf(object value)
            {
                var valueControl = value as Control;

                if (valueControl != null)
                {
                    return IndexOf(valueControl);
                }

                return -1;
            }

            void IList.Insert(int index, object value)
            {
                var valueControl = value as Control;

                if (valueControl != null)
                {
                    lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                    {
                        _controls.Insert(index, valueControl);
                    }
                }
            }

            bool IList.IsFixedSize => false;

            object IList.this[int index]
            {
                get
                {
                    return this[index];
                }
                set
                {
                    var valueControl = value as Control;

                    if (valueControl != null)
                    {
                        lock (_internalSyncRoot)
                        {
                            _controls[index] = valueControl;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            void IList.Remove(object control)
            {
                var controlControl = control as Control;

                if (controlControl != null)
                {
                    Remove(controlControl);
                }
            }

            void IList.RemoveAt(int index)
            {
                RemoveAt(index);
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make your lock members read-only!!

Comment: @TopinFrassi Whoops, my bad! :) I won't edit the question, so feel free to add it to an answer.

Comment: I do not understand one important thing: WinForns **is not thread safe**. To have a threadbare control collection won't change this (because controls still should be created on UI thread, unless you carefully avoid to materialize handle during initialization). What's then the point of locking? You just impact performance in the **only available scenario**. Yes it **may** be done but with much much care and in limited situations (winforms itself throws exceptions when it detect a cross-thread situation). Not something you can hide in a "thread-safe" collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**All** your members should be `readonly`! None of them should ever change.

You don't want someone to set your lock members to `null`. That would be bad, I don't think you possibly could change the parent `Control`, that would be weird, and I don't see the need to create a new instance of the list of child controls!

```
lock (_internalSyncRoot)
{
    foreach (Control c in _controls)
    {
        if (c.Name == key)
        {
            return c;
        }
    }

    throw new KeyNotFoundException();
}
```

I have absolutely no explanation to this, but I have a guts feeling it'd be better if you threw the exception outside the `lock` statement. A `lock` should do as little as possible, so I think you should throw outside the `lock`.

I'm no threading expert, ok? But this also feels wrong :

```
public virtual void AddRange(Control[] controls)
{
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        Add(control);
    }
}
```

Everytime you call `Add`, you'll obtain a `lock`, then release the `lock`, then obtain the `lock`, etc. Consider obtaining a `lock` once and then calling `InternalAdd` in the loop. you'll avoid weird locking.

Finally, I hate regions, you know that already :p

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> public virtual int GetChildIndex(Control child, bool throwException)
> {
>     lock (_internalSyncRoot)
>     {
>         if (_controls.Contains(child))
>         {
>             return _controls.IndexOf(child);
>         }
>
>         if (throwException)
>         {
>             throw new ArgumentException();
>         }
>
>         return -1;
>     }
> }
> ```

well, why don't you just use `_controls.IndexOf()` like so

```
public virtual int GetChildIndex(Control child, bool throwException)
{
    lock (_internalSyncRoot)
    {
        int index = _controls.IndexOf(child);
        if (index == -1 && throwException)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        return index;
    }
}
```

---

> ```
> public virtual void SetChildIndex(Control child, int newIndex)
> {
>     lock (_internalSyncRoot)
>     {
>         if (_controls.Contains(child))
>         {
>             if (newIndex >= Count)
>             {
>                 _controls.Remove(child);
>                 _controls.Add(child);
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 _controls.Remove(child);
>                 _controls.Insert(newIndex, child);
>             }
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             throw new ArgumentException();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

here I would use a guard clause to reduce the horizontal spacing. By using `Math.Min` with `newIdex` and `Count` it could be simplified to

```
public virtual void SetChildIndex(Control child, int newIndex)
{
    lock (_internalSyncRoot)
    {
        if (!_controls.Contains(child))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        newIndex = Math.Min(newIndex, Count);

        _controls.Remove(child);
        _controls.Insert(newIndex, child);

    }
}
```